# Rails routes - index page for subdomain and standard url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the account_location plugin in my rails app and have the following route

```
map.root :controller => "dashboard", :action => 'index'
```

This route match's on both subdomain.domain.com and www.domain.com

How can I set it up so these two domains match different routes?

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of an indirect answer, but you might want to look into using [subdomain_fu](http://github.com/mbleigh/subdomain-fu). If you use `subdomain_fu` you'll be able to change that route.

For example:

```
map.root :controller => "dashboard", :action => 'index', :conditions => { :subdomain => false }
```

would not match requests with a subdomain.

Here's a [great Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/123-subdomains) if you're interested.